# articles with positional titles

Tags: articles

When a common noun is used as a proper noun or given as a title to a person or place should it be preceded by an article? If yes, with which article?  For example:

> Rahul is called king of good times

or:

> Rahul is called **a** king of good times

or

> Rahul is called **the** king of good times.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those could be considered grammatically correct, although I might use upper case letters or quotation marks, especially for the first one:

> Rahul is called, "King of Good Times”.

As for which article should be used, that depends on how many "kings of good times” are in your circle of friends. If Rahul is clearly the only one, use *the*. If there are a few others, use *a*.